# Unable to login to Ubuntu after creating partition for windows

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, login

I've recently created a partition from Windows Disk Management Utility for Windows as 'New Volume (:F)' which was in 'Disk 0' but when I rebooted the system back I was unable to login to Ubuntu and whenever I tried to enter password the screen gets black and I was again welcomed by login screen. My complete Ubuntu is on 'Disk 1'. I need to login to my Ubuntu account as there's some really important data on it. Any help would be grateful.

[Windows disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir8J5.png)

[GPARTED IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvzpw.jpg)

[GPARTED IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6hTs.jpg)

[cat /etc/fstab output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q7hk.jpg)

[sudo blkid output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Xob.jpg)

Comment: If you're getting as far as the Ubuntu login screen, then maybe there's something wrong with fstab file. Boot into recovery and check the contents of `/etc/fstab`. Add this to your question.

Comment: BEFORE creating the F: drive, did Windows and Ubuntu both work fine? How did you make room for F: and how did you create F:? Do you have another user account on Ubuntu that you can try to log info, just to see if that works? Are you able to post a screenshot(s) of `gparted` view of both drives (that's better for us Ubuntu troubleshooters)?

Comment: @ToDo I've added your required logs of /etc/fstab

Comment: @heynnema Before creating the F: drive they both worked fine. I just allocated a space from sda to windows, I only have one user on Ubuntu which is 'sahil' and 'root'.

Comment: If your /etc/fstab is correct, then it looks like you overwrote your Ubuntu /home with the newly created F: NTFS partition. This is why I asked "*How did you make room for F: and how did you create F:*". Let me confirm that. Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid | grep -v loop`. Also, why do you have two swap partitions?

Comment: @ToDo `/etc/fstab` by itself won't tell you anything... other than that they have two swap partitions (which makes no sense), and what was where at install time. You'd need at least a `sudo blkid` command to make anything useful out of it. See my prior comment, and I'm requesting that. With it, I'll be able to confirm if the user overwrote their /home partition.

Comment: @heynnema I've added `sudo blkid` output. Now is there any way by which I can get back to Ubuntu without fresh install?

Comment: It seems you overwrote your home partition. Was there anything important on that particular partition?

Comment: @ToDo **I documented that conclusion 4 hours earlier**. No reason to repeat it. After looking at `/etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`, I've confirmed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your `/etc/fstab`, and `sudo blkid`, and your `gparted` screenshots, it looks like you overwrote your Ubuntu `/home` partition `/dev/sda1` with a new fresh NTFS partition.

You have to be very careful when working with tools like Window's `Disk Management` and Ubuntu's `gparted`.

I don't know of any reliable way to recover. Theoretically it might be possible to delete the current `/dev/sda1` NTFS partition, manually recreate a ext4 partition with the exact same partition parameters as original, and maybe recover... theoretically. I can't assist with that.

Next step... delete the `/dev/sda1` NTFS partition and reinstall Ubuntu. Hopefully you have good backups and can restore your important data.

Comment: Yeah, I've reinstalled the system. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SahilSilare You're very welcome.